# is there any way to determine the date a domain DNS record like MX record was published?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

We need a way to determine when exactly a DNS record such as MX was published for a domain. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Your domain or someone elses?

Comment: It'd have to be something like http://www.domaintools.com/research/whois-history/ but I've never heard of one that monitored MX records.

Comment: Not our domain. Third party domains. We need to determine the MX publish date for some reasons.

Comment: Without admin access to the DNS server(s) to look at the actual records, I don't know of a tool that would find creation timestamps for DNS records.  Even a DIG with +all doesn't return that info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short of a kind of crawler that keep historical snapshots like the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php) but for DNS, no, this is not possible.

If you suspect that the `MX` record update may have been the most recent change to the DNS zone, then you can always check the zone serial number in the `SOA` record. One very frequently used convention for the format of the serial number is **YYYYmmddnn** where **nn** is a serial number for multiple modifications made on the same day. This *might* give you a clue as to when the zone was most recently updated. But this convention is not necessarily in use, and it can lie even if it is, and it doesn't tell you what was modified. The only thing I would infer from it is that *probably* nothing at all has changed in the zone since the date that appears in the `SOA`. Probably.